# Create Windows CE application installer, VS2008

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, installation, windows-ce

Just wrote an application for Windows CE 6, how do I package it into an installer so I can distribute to customer? 
I am using VS2008 (VB.net), .NET 3.5 CF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Smart Device CAB Project in VS2008.

Just follow the [Walkthrough: Packaging a Smart Device Solution for Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Also there are some tools which allows you to Create CABinet packages that can be used to install applications on Windows CE / Mobile platforms.